# I cannot set working directory to one drive but I have no problems with setting it to the computer

Tags: onedrive, working-directory

I can set the working directory to any file that is on my computer e.g.,
`setwd("C:/Users/AnneO/Downloads` However, I have encountered on error  *cannot change the working directory*, when I try to change it to some folder on my One Drive e.g., `setwd("C:/Users/AnneO/OneDrive - University/30052018")`.

The error started appearing suddenly, as everything worked fine one week ago.
I tried installing and installing the new version of R/R studio but problem remains.

Thanks,
Anne

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It just shows: ```Error in setwd("C:/Users/AnneO/OneDrive - University/30052018") : cannot change working directory```. Nothing else appears.